# How to load JSON data with square bracket

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit

I'm calling data from Breaking bad API https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/character/random
I'm unable to get data. I think it's because the main Response file has square brackets that I need to call first. But I don't know how to call it. Can I get some help?

Here's my API interface

```
interface APIRequest {

    @GET("character/random")

    suspend fun getInfo() : Response<List<ResponseBB>>
}
```

ResponseBB Class

```
data class ResponseBB(

    @field:SerializedName("ResponseBB")
    val responseBB: List<ResponseBBItem?>? = null
)

    data class ResponseBBItem(
    
            @field:SerializedName("birthday")
            val birthday: Any? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("img")
            val img: String? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("better_call_saul_appearance")
            val betterCallSaulAppearance: Any? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("occupation")
            val occupation: List<String?>? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("appearance")
            val appearance: List<Int?>? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("portrayed")
            val portrayed: String? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("name")
            val name: String? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("nickname")
            val nickname: String? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("char_id")
            val charId: Int? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("category")
            val category: String? = null,
        
            @field:SerializedName("status")
            val status: String? = null
        )
```

Client object

```
object Client {

    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()

    val  api = retrofit.create(APIRequest::class.java)
}
```

Here's my function to call result in the main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var TAG = "MainActivity"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getCharacterInfo()

        linearLayout.setOnClickListener {
            getCharacterInfo()
        }
    }

    private fun getCharacterInfo() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = Client.api.getInfo()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val data = response.body()
                    Log.d(TAG, data.toString())
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Picasso.get().load(data!!.img).into(ivImage)
                        tvName.text = data.name
                        tvOccupation.text = data.toString()
                        tvActor.text = data.toString()
                        tvAppearance.text = data.appearance.toString()
                        tvStatus.text = data.status
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Cannot Load Data" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you try to use coroutines in retrofit, I recommend that you do not work with Response, change it to call and remove the suspend.

```
interface APIRequest {

    @GET("character/random")

    fun getInfo() : Call<List<ResponseBB>>
}
```

In your Global Scope you can call it this way:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    try{
       val response = Client.api.getInfo().await()
    }catch(e:Exception){}
}
```

you can use the version 2.9.0 in retrofit and gson Converter